# C++ - LNK2019 unresolved external symbol - Can't seem to find what I'm missing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, directx

I know this is a common problem and I can see quite a few questions about LNK2019 but I can't for the life of me find what I'm missing.

I am working on a C++ DirectX project and I want to use the **DirectXTK** library ([Direct X Tool Kit](http://directxtk.codeplex.com/)). I have included the project in my solution and it builds fine.

I've also included the **ScreenGrab.h** header I want to use in my own project. Intellisense picks up the function definitions from **ScreenGrab.h** fine and so I have called **SaveDDSTextureToFile()**.

But when I go to build the project I get the LNK2019 error on **SaveDDSTextureToFile().** I'm assuming this means it knows where the definition is (in the header) but can't find the implementation of the function in the .obj or .lib, is this correct?

I assume I need to tell the linker where these files are? I tried doing that in **Properties->Configuration Settings->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories** but I still get the LNK2019 error.

Does anyone know what I'm still missing?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you add the .lib as input? You don't just need to specify where it is, but also which one it is.

Comment: You need the actual .c/.cpp file or library that implements SaveDDSTextureToFile

Comment: Hi, thanks both of you I saw the Linker->Input tab just after I posted the question and realized what I hadn't done. Thanks for pointing it out and I ended up answering my own question below for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupidly, I didn't add the lib to the Linker oops.

Basically for anyone else that forgets this step - after you've added the directory to Linker->General, go over to Linker->Input and add the name of the .lib to "Additional Dependencies" - so for me I typed "DirectXTK.lib" here (without the quotes).

If I hadn't added the directory to Linker->General I also could have typed "../folder1/folder2/folder-etc/DirectXTK.lib" here depending on the relative path from where my project is.

Sorry for wasting people's time and I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your linker->general->additional library directories configuration is for all configurations, and not just "release" or "debug". Try adding the static library file (depending on the Direct3D version you're using) to your project from the SDK directories - if it compiles then you've definitely done something wrong with the linker configurations.